# How to add numbers in TextBox by using loop

Tags: excel, vba

For a VBA code in Excel, I have 24 TextBoxs with 8 rows 3 columns. The aim is that I want the input values in the textbox to be the same in cells by using a for loop to shorten down the code

This is my code[but it is not correct]:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range

Set wks = Sheet1

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)

For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 0 To 2
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox1.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox2.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox3.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox4.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox5.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox6.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox7.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox8.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox9.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox10.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox11.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox12.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox13.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox14.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox15.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox16.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox17.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox18.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox19.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox20.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox21.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox22.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox23.Text
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = TextBox24.Text
    Next j

Next i


End Sub
```

[My TextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Stb.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
Sub Populate()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rowWidth As Long
    rowWidth = 3
    For i = 0 To 23
        'determine row and column
        r = Int(i / 3) + 1
        c = i Mod 3 + 1
        Me.Controls("textBox" & (i + 1)).Value = Cells(r, c).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that you need adjust code a little so it will loop through desired range.

Note also that you need to place that code in userform code :)

Comment: @CeeSupa You should accept the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you can name your textbox with the number i and j. For example for cell(1,1) or or range("A1"), you can name your textbox as "Textbox11" then when looping through u can use Controls("Textbox" & i & j). Something like this below.

[image]

```
'

Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Starting Range A1
For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 1 To 3
    'if you want to have the value from the cell to be copied to the textbox, the formula below should be the other way round.
    wks.Cells(i, j).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & i & j).Text
    Next j
Next i

'
```

Comment: Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range

Set wks = Sheet1

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)

For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 0 To 2
    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = Controls("Textbox" & i & j).Text
    Next j
Next i
    
    
End Sub

Comment: I was just giving an idea before, but i have redited the code to start from range A1 and end at range C8.

Comment: note that the if you want the cells' value to be in textbox then the code within the For loop should be Me.Controls("Textbox" & i & j).Text = wks.Cells(i, j).Value

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can't run the code that you have corrected, and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I just realized your code in setting the worksheets is incorrect. it should be Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1"). Re-edited the code.

Comment: wks.Cells(i, j).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & i & j).Text            it is this line that the program said i need to debug

Comment: did you copy the code to a button in the userform? or in the form initialize?

Comment: Did you rename the textbox as shown in the picture above? if do not want to rename it then Michal's answer will be better.